# Try Except Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

quería saber si podéis explicarme que significa `raise`. Es que no se que significa exactamente **raise err**.En definitiva no se que hace este `except`, ¿se puede poner una condición? (Me refiero en la linea de `except`, en donde pone `socket.error as err`)  Por ejemplo aquí:

```
try:

    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.sock.bind((listenip, listenport))
    _, self.listenport = self.sock.getsockname()

except socket.error as err: raise err
```

Espero que podáis ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Es la forma de lanzar un error, en este caso de relanzarlo, tras haberlo capturado. En el código que has puesto no parece tener mucho sentido, ya que lo captura para volver a lanzarlo sin hacer nada. En general puedes hacer algo como:

```
try:
  # codigo que puede lanzar una excepción
except Exception as e:
  if not puedo_tratar(e):
    raise #no hace falta poner la excepción de nuevo
  tratar_exception(e)
```